# Querying for multiple items based on some inner property or properties in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I apologize if the title is not worded properly. I am seeking advice on the recommended way to perform the following operation on Firebase.

I am using Firebase for a group collaboration kind of app (think of Whatsapp). A user registers using his phone number and is added as a user to the Firebase database. A user is stored as follows on Firebase

```
users
 -KGvMIPwul2dUYABCDEF
   countryCode: 1
   id: -KGvMIPwul2dUYABCDEF
   mobileNumber: 1231231234 
   name: Varun Gupta
```

Whenever a user opens the app, I want to check who all in user's phone contact list is also using my app and present those contacts in the app. The phone number is used to check if a person in the phone contacts is using the app. To achieve this, I store the user contacts list to Firebase which triggers a Firebase function to compute the contacts also using my app and store them separately on Firebase.

To figure out who is using my app, I create a map of all the users in Firebase keyed on the phone number and a combination of country code and phone number. The value is the user ID which would be `-KGvMIPwul2dUYABCDEF` for the above example. So, the map would have the following two entries for the user

```
{
  1231231234: -KGvMIPwul2dUYABCDEF
  11231231234: -KGvMIPwul2dUYABCDEF
}
```

I create the above for all the users and then I just query for each contact, if there is an entry for the user's phone number in the map and figure out the list of users who are using the app.

Below are the excerpts from the code. Right now it is done in a `firebase-queue` worker but I intend to move it to a Firebase function

```
    // This piece of code is used to read the users in Firebase and create a map as described above
    ref.child('users').on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
      var uid = snapshot.key;
      var userData = snapshot.val();
      // Match against both mobileNumber and the combination of countryCode and mobileNumber
      // Sanity check
      if(userData.mobileNumber && userData.countryCode) {
        contactsMap.set(sanitizePhoneNumber(userData.mobileNumber), uid);
        contactsMap.set(sanitizePhoneNumber(userData.countryCode + userData.mobileNumber), uid);
      }
    });


    // This piece of code is used to figure out which contacts are using the app
    contactsData.forEach((contact) => {
      contact.phoneNumbers.forEach((phoneNumber) => {
        var contactsMapEntry = contactsMap.get(sanitizePhoneNumber(phoneNumber))
        // Don't add user himself to the contacts if he is present in the contacts
        if(contactsMapEntry && contactsMapEntry !== uid && !contactsObj[contactsMapEntry]) {
          const contactObj = {
            name: createContactName(contact),
            mobileNumber: phoneNumber.number,
            id: contactsMapEntry
          }
          contactsObj[contactsMapEntry] = contactObj
          currentContacts.push(contactObj)
        }
      });
    });

    // After figuring out the currentContacts, I do some processing and they are pushed to Firebase which are then synched with the app
```

My concern is that as the number of users increases, this will start to become slow because I am reading all the users from the Firebase creating this map in memory for every request to figure out the contacts who are using the app or would I be okay with this brute force kind of method and shouldn't worry too much.

Should I consider duplicating data like below also

```
contacts
  1231231234: -KGvMIPwul2dUYABCDEF
  11231231234: -KGvMIPwul2dUYABCDEF
```

and then just query for `/contacts/{contact phone number}`

If there is an even better method to achieve this workflow, please suggest.

Comment: Instead of describing the code that you're concerned about, edit your question to [include the minimal code that reproduces the concern](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen I have added the code that is used to perform the described operations.

Comment: Is there some reason that doing a `firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('mobileNumber').equalTo('1231231234')` would not work?

Comment: @torazaburo It will work for matching against just the mobileNumber but I also wanted to match against the combination of country code and mobile number. I think for that I should just store one more entry for the user which is a combination of country code and mobile number and run a similar query. Thanks!